# Is there any way to know when the game saves?

Tags: adventure-time-etdbidk

I've figured out that the game autosaves at certain points, but I am not entirely sure when that happens.  Is there a way to know? Or does it save consistently at certain spots or events?

Answer (score 1):

(Note that this knowledge is for the Xbox 360 version.  This may vary between different consoles.  Additionally, most games for said system usually have a warning upon starting the game about how it saves, showing the specific icon used to indicate it is saving.)

From what I recall, there is a snail-like character with a brown shell that appears on screen to indicate that the game is saving.  This will generally happen at the following three points:

1. Entering the Dungeon
2. Exiting the Dungeon (death, hub level, or after a boss fight)
3. Doing almost anything in the Candy Kingdom

There are no mid-dungeon saves; you must exit the dungeon in one form or another for progress to be save. If you power off in the middle of a dungeon run, it has already recorded what tokens and sub-weapons you brought with you; those are gone for good.  Any money found is completely gone, as well, including any you may have carried into the dungeon by use of a specific token (Mind Games).

Above ground, most things will trigger a save point.  Changing characters, upgrading stats, buying items from the store, and using the Sub-Weapon box.  Even just interacting with the above may trigger a save.